# How is video programming in Linux compared to DirectShow?

Tags: ubuntu, directshow, video-capture

I have once been programming with `DirectShow` for Windows, to grab images from digital camera and remove the background on the fly. Now I want to convert it to Linux, but I have no experience. I have tried to read the kernel source, but it seems a little too complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popular API on Unix is [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/), but for image processing don't forget [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).